# how to assign String type data from JTextField to a variable

Tags: java, swing, jframe, primitive

I can successfully do this for `int` but when I try to do it for text2var and text3var (which are String)  it does not work. Error below, same thing occur for text3var.

```
try
{

    text1var = Integer.parseInt(text1.getText());
    text2var = text2var.getText();
    text3var = text3var.getText();
    text4var = Integer.parseInt(text4.getText());

    output = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("datafile.dat") );
    output.writeInt(text1var);
    output.writeUTF(text2var);
    output.writeUTF(text3var);
    output.writeInt(text4var);
    output.close();
}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is pretty much exactly what the error message says it is.

`text2var` is not a `JTextField`, it is a `string`. Try calling `getText()` on a `JTextField`, maybe `text2`?

Comment: @sirio happy to help!